# Loading items into a RecyclerView with stackFromEnd = true doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a chat app and i'm trying to ensure that when the user opens the screen the items display from the bottom with the most recent right above the input area. I've used a custom view for the input area and both the recycler and the custom view are within a ConstraintLayout.

My problem is that when I load items into the list, if the number of items is greater than the size of the recycler, it will not fully show the last item. When I make the input area visibility = Gone then the items display properly at the bottom. It's almost like the recyclers LinearLayoutManager thinks that the height of the Recycler is of the screen without the input field. I've manually printed out the size of the views and used layout inspector to ensure that the recycler is indeed drawn in the correct location (above the input and below the navigation bar).

What could be causing such an issue? I should note that whenever you click on a Linkified text in a chat bubble that the list scrolls a small amount equal to the offset that's incorrect when you open the screen. Clearly something is not measuring right here and not sure where to begin.

I should also note that if I try to add a post with smoothScroll it will go to the end of the list but then whenever a new item appears in the list from sending a message the items above the most recently added one seem to jump up a little with an unnecessary animation. It's like the last item in the list is in some special state?

if you're curious this is my scrolling function:

```
private fun scrollToFirstItem(dueToKeyboard: Boolean = false) {
    val stackingFromEnd = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).stackFromEnd

    if (stackingFromEnd) {
        val firstPosition = recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount?: 0 - 1
        if (dueToKeyboard ) {
            recyclerView.scrollBy(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        } else {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(firstPosition)
        }
        recyclerView.post { recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(firstPosition) }
    } else {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
}
```

And my xml for my fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        layout="@layout/compose_new_message_include"/>

<com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/conversationEpoxyRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/composeView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/conversation_item_inbound"/>

<include layout="@layout/conversation_pip_view"
 android:id="@+id/selectedMediaContainer"/>

<****.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/composeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm so lost..

Comment: Provide your xml file code

Comment: I have implemented the same. I am just confused with what you say. So when you send a message do you append that message onto the same list or show completely as a different item?

Comment: appended onto the list

Comment: what actually ended up fixing it was reverselayout and stackfromend both had to be true... which is kinda contrary to documentation so clearly an android bug

Answer (score 0):

To me this feels like more of an issue in the layout rather than in the scrolling function. I hope that this can be resolved easily if you use a *Relative Layout* instead of a *Linear Layout*. So in case if it may be helpful, i'll add my solution below using a *Relative Layout*.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/input_field">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in case if it is not clear what i have done, an *EditText* element is set to align to the bottom of parent which is a Relative Layout. Then a *RecyclerView* is added so that *RecylerView* will be always constraint above the *EditText* but not overlapped.

Comment: So I actually use a constraint layout here, which is just a performance oriented RelativeLayout. Moving forward try not to use RelativeLayout for any more of your layouts as ConstraintLayout is the new norm

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, except the restrictions you added to `recycleview` design, I see that you are setting the `recycleview` to top of  `searchView` `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"` while the `searchView` view is not restricted as should it be.

It's better when using `ConstraintLayout` to restrict every view inorder avoid unexpected behaviors, because every view has a relation with other view will be effected with other view *(x, y)*, therefore your `searchView` should be look like:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    layout="@layout/compose_new_message_include"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the size of arraylist of your data to smoothScrollToPosition

```
var linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
recyclerView.layoutManager=linearLayoutManager
recyclerView.adapter=adapter
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(dataMsgs.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some years back and I solved it with **scrollToPositionWithOffset** (support library).  Of course this was before constraint was used....

I kept my newer items at the bottom, too.  The code I used for scrolling after inserting an item was:

```
((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(getItemCount() - 1, 0);
```

To scroll and adjust the awkward positioning after removing an item, I used:

```
View vTopCard = layoutManager.getChildAt(0);
// Get its adapter position
final int topCardPos = layoutManager.getPosition(vTopCard);
// Get top of card position
int topOffset = layoutManager.getDecoratedTop(vTopCard);
int cardMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_vertical_margin);

((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(topCardPos, topOffset - cardMargin);
```

The **getDecoratedTop** helps with the "bounce" and final positioning, as does factoring the vertical margin.

I hope this helps (at least part of your issue)!  Like I said, this is old code (when I was learning to program Android and Java at the same time), so if I left something out, let me know and I'll reexamine the app's code in more detail (though, I'll have to find the time).

Good luck!